# Looping through all combinations of columns in a dataframe

Tags: r

How can I loop over all possible combinations of columns in a dataframe, and later use those combination of variables in a group by function? For example, if I have a dataframe with 2 columns, A and B, I want to run a loop that can first group by A, then B and lastly AB?

P.S: I have tried combn function, but in that we can only choose a fixed number of combination (2,3 etc). I, however, need all possible combinations of columns, which essentially is equal to the number of columns. For 4 columns that will be: all combinations of 1, 2, 3 and 4. Thanks!

Comment: Hi..You have been posting the same question again and again without any improvement to it. Please include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) along with expected output.

Comment: I realize that Reprexes are the current orthodoxy in this site. Since you didn't provide one, I'll take a guess.  See answer below.

If you are taking all possible combinations of columns, you may wish to consider that your data structure is not well suited for your problem.  Back up a bit and try to get a sense of the big picture.  Once you have all these combinations, what are you going to do with them?  

Just because you can formulate a problem, doesn't mean it's the one  you should be solving.

Comment: Hi @michael..this is exactly what I want (A, B, C, AB, AC, BC, ABC).. thanks again for explaining through the dataset. Furthermore, I would like to pass these combinations through a   group_by function along with other columns of the dataframe. For example group_by(date, combination)..so i need to run a loop that can take one combination at a time and pass it through the group_by function. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks again!

Comment: Using the function from the linked post: `x <- colnames(mtcars)[1:3]; result <- c(x, unlist(make_combinations(x), recursive = FALSE)); result` should give you what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the input is `s <- c("a","b","c","d")`, all combinations can be obtained through below:

```
Map(function(v) apply(v,2, function(x) paste0(x,collapse = "")),sapply(seq_along(s), function(k) combn(s,k)))
```

which gives:

```
[[1]]
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"

[[2]]
[1] "ab" "ac" "ad" "bc" "bd" "cd"

[[3]]
[1] "abc" "abd" "acd" "bcd"

[[4]]
[1] "abcd"
```

Besides, if you want it all combinations with separate letters, then you can use:

```
> Map(as.data.frame, sapply(seq_along(s), function(k) t(combn(s,k))))
[[1]]
  V1
1  a
2  b
3  c
4  d

[[2]]
  V1 V2
1  a  b
2  a  c
3  a  d
4  b  c
5  b  d
6  c  d

[[3]]
  V1 V2 V3
1  a  b  c
2  a  b  d
3  a  c  d
4  b  c  d

[[4]]
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  a  b  c  d
```

Hope the above can do help for your question

Comment: Thanks a lot @ Thomasls..your code helps. Is there a way to separate the letters with combination 2 and above? For example, instead of "ab", is there a way I can get "a","b"? This is still one combination but are separated. Actually the Group by function cannot read "ab" as no column of this name exists. However, if its "a","b", it will read them separately, yet l group by them together. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: I added another type of output as your described. Hope this is what you need @Stats

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer, but once you show your desired output, I'll finish it.  Here's a sample reprex:

```r
 df=data.frame(A=letters[1:5],
               B=letters[3:7],
               C=letters[22:26])
```

Here's the data frame

```
> df
    A B C
  --------
1 | a c v
2 | b d w
3 | c e x
4 | d f y
5 | e g z
```

Odds are, this is **not** what you were imagining,but it's  a starting point.

When you think about **all* the combinations of columns, are you thinking they would be appended as follows?

Is this what you were thinking, roughly?  Assuming you would be doing this for all the subsets of columns.

```
df$AB=paste(df$A,df$B,sep='')

|A  |B  |C  |AB |
|:--|:--|:--|:--|
|a  |c  |v  |ac |
|b  |d  |w  |bd |
|c  |e  |x  |ce |
|d  |f  |y  |df |
|e  |g  |z  |eg |
```

One of the problems I see if you  push forward in this direction is how you're gong to automate the naming of the columns.  My suggestion would be to back up and figure out how these values will be used once you get them.